# bash mkdir and cp error on variable path "cannot create directory : No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, mkdir, cp

I'm trying to automate copying the content from a variable path (my camera) into a partially-user-defined path (desktop+date+event). The problem is that mkdir and cp complain saying that the directory cannot be created, but I don't understand why despite having DuckDuckGo'd for over an hour. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo -n "Enter event name and press [ENTER]: "
read event
sleep 0

day=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
month=`date +%Y-%m`
media="/media/F009-64A5"

source="${media}/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM/*"
target="/home/kv/Desktop/$month/$day"\_"$event"

mkdir $target
cp -pr $source $target
```

Comment: what is output if you `echo $target` before the `mkdir`?

Comment: /home/kv/Desktop/2011-08/2011-08-18_asdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`mkdir -p $target` will create the path with all necessary subpaths.

Comment: We have an issue where a customer of ours is using a script in which mkdir -p <some_directory> fails with "No such file or directory". That is, mkdir complains about a missing directory despite being invoked with the -p option! Running the same command on our site works fine. I don't understand how mkdir can complain about a missing directory when it's explicitly told to create all missing directories!

Comment: Are your and the remote servers exactly the same? Or does the client use a stripped down version like busybox? The -p-Option might not be available there.

Comment: @antred if the command was copied from somewhere else that doesn't use the standard dash `-` but some other special char dash variant, it will cause the error `No such file or directory` because mkdir doesn't recognize the option `p` and instead tries to create two directories named `<special-char-dash-variant>p` and `<some_directory/sub>` and fails creating the second one.